# Como criar um elemento com níveis e depois adicionar elementos em um dos seus subníveis com jquery?

Tags: jquery

Preciso criar o objeto com a  estrutura abaixo e inserir options.

```js
 myElem = $("<div class='row'> <div class='form-group'> <label for='multiple-selected' class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 control-label'>Teste</label> <div class='col-md-5'><select id='multiple-selected' multiple='multiple'></div> </div> </div>");
```

E depois inserir option nesse objeto.
Não quero fazer concatenando texto puro (montando o html na mão).
Tem como fazer isso com append? Pensei no appendTo() mas o objeto ainda não foi inserido no html alguém teria uma dica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesmo sem o elemento estar inserido no DOM podes usar os métodos do jQuery.

Testa com `var $select = myElem.find('select');`

```
var myElem = $("<div class='row'> <div class='form-group'> <label for='multiple-selected' class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 control-label'>Teste</label> <div class='col-md-5'><select id='multiple-selected' multiple='multiple'></div> </div> </div>");
var $select = myElem.find('select');
console.log($select); // dá [select#multiple-selected, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: undefined, selector: "select"]
```